# [self.view addSubview:_topViewController.view]; autorotation issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uideviceorientation

Really been stuck for this for weeks. I am using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController), and i want one view, to be able to rotate to landscape and portrait, as it is a landscape photo, and needs to make use of available space, whilst i don't want the rest of the app to rotate, just stay in landscape.

I'm sure the autorotation methods are not getting called as it uses this technique to switch to views...

```
- (void)setTopViewController:(UIViewController *)theTopViewController
{
  CGRect topViewFrame = _topViewController ? _topViewController.view.frame : self.view.bounds;

  [self removeTopViewSnapshot];
  [_topViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
  [_topViewController willMoveToParentViewController:_topViewController];
  [_topViewController removeFromParentViewController];

  _topViewController = theTopViewController;

  [self addChildViewController:self.topViewController];
  [self.topViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

  [_topViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:self.autoResizeToFillScreen];
  [_topViewController.view setFrame:topViewFrame];
  _topViewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
  _topViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;

    [self.view addSubview:_topViewController.view];
}
```

And on my initialviewcontroller...

```
self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
```

So it's just stacking on top, rather than switching to this view. So, its always listening to initial view controllers rotation methods...

Help is much appreciated, as i said i have been stuck for days...

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you add some more explanation of the problem, perhaps add some more of your code.

Comment: Well, i've built an app, and i want all but one view to be portrait, so i've added the autorotation iOS6 methods, but they are not getting called as [self.view addSubview:_topViewController.view]; adds onto top of stack i guess, take a look at the link and you'll soon understand how it works. I just need to be able to use the autorotate methods, like 
`- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations, - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate, - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation `

Comment: Please do not shout in a question. It is annoying and gives bad impression to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for a few hours, finally i can make this work..

First, you need to create a subview of `ECSLidingViewController` and put this code:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
     return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations]; 
 }

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
     return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
 }

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
     return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
 }
```

You also need to create a category of `UINavigationController` and override this code

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
     return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
 }

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
     return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
 }

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
     return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
 }

@end
```

Hope this work for you..

Comment: That's how I got it to work in the end! Just seen this, cheers though buddy!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem: if you instantiate a view controller, the add its view to another view controller´s view through `addSubview`, then the first controller will not get any autorotation related called.

To cope with this use case, Apple added to iOS5 what is called as *`UIViewController` Containment*, where you can add a child controller to another controller; then all relevant methods (`viewWillAppear/Disappear`; autorotation methods etc. will be auto-routed to child controllers).

Here are the essential methods you might need to call:

```
addChildViewController:
removeFromParentViewController
willMoveToParentViewController:
didMoveToParentViewController:
```

Have a look at [Implementing a Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for detailed info.

[Here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/) you can find a tutorial that will give you step-by-step instructions as to how to use containment.

Keep in mind that this will only work for iOS>5, so if you need to support iOS4, you are out of luck. In any case, you might try to build a workaround by relaying the relevant messages to your sub controllers. E.g., in a app of mine, this is what `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` look like:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

 [self.mainButtonBarController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation
                                                               duration:duration];
 [self.boardController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation
                                                               duration:duration];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

 [self.mainButtonBarController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
 [self.boardController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

I.e., they simply forward the same message to the child controllers. You can do the same for other methods you need (`shouldAutorotate...`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, total newbie, but would i add this to the ECSliding class, like this: `[_topViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:_topViewController];
[self.view addSubview: _topViewController.view];
[_topViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];`

Comment: Could you take a look at ECSliding, and tell me where to implement this code etc, I'm sorry for being a pest, but totally lost... Many thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: I don´t know `ECSliding` but I don´t think you need to modify `ECSliding`; simply, when you call `addSubview`, also call the containment related methods... if you need more help, post in your question, the way you are creating the ECSlidingController and how you add to it the sub-controllers.

Comment: had a look... do you mean it is not working like that or what?

Comment: Nope, i've added autorotation methods to my views controller, and its just not calling them...

Comment: ok, just an hypothesis. You are removing one controller with another. The way I see this done in the tutorial I linked is: ` [fromViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
 [self addChildViewController:toViewController];`. would you mind trying just thosw 2 methods? or referring to the tutorial where it deals with transitions (of course you can ignore the core animation part).

Comment: willMoveToParentViewController is already in method, added the other and no luck...

Comment: mind that willMoveToParent has `nil` as an argument. don´t know if this will make any difference.

Comment: No luck either... Is it because im not using setRootViewController, and instead using addSubview?

Comment: you need using `setRootController`, but this is not related to using `addSubview` (you can do both).

Comment: Oh right, i just thought that subview needed to be replaced with this for iOS6. :/ Any other ideas, totally stuck, and been trying for days!?